# How to convert html files into pdf using itextsharp in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, itext

I am converting html files into pdf using itextsharp in mvc. I have refered this link. http://www.rswebsols.com/tutorials/programming/asp-net-generate-pdf-html-itextsharp 
In this method they are passing string pHTML as parameter. I did not get this? do I need to convert html into string format and then I should pass that string to getpdf method? How can I convert html into string? I have the path of html document.

Comment: Don't use that example, they use the deprecated `HTMLWorker`. Refer to the official documentation and use `XMLWorker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

using System.Data;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace HTMLtoPDF
{
    public partial class ConvertHTMLtoPDF : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadAsPDF();
        }

        public void DownloadAsPDF()
        {
            try
            {
                string strHtml = string.Empty;
                string pdfFileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\files\\" + "GenerateHTMLTOPDF.pdf";

                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                dvHtml.RenderControl(hw);
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                strHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();

                CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(strHtml, pdfFileName);

                Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", "GenerateHTMLTOPDF.pdf"));
                Response.WriteFile(pdfFileName);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(string HtmlStream, string FileName)
        {
            try
            {
                object TargetFile = FileName;
                string ModifiedFileName = string.Empty;
                string FinalFileName = string.Empty;


                GeneratePDF.HtmlToPdfBuilder builder = new GeneratePDF.HtmlToPdfBuilder(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
                GeneratePDF.HtmlPdfPage first = builder.AddPage();
                first.AppendHtml(HtmlStream);
                byte[] file = builder.RenderPdf();
                File.WriteAllBytes(TargetFile.ToString(), file);

                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(TargetFile.ToString());
                ModifiedFileName = TargetFile.ToString();
                ModifiedFileName = ModifiedFileName.Insert(ModifiedFileName.Length - 4, "1");

                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, new FileStream(ModifiedFileName, FileMode.Append), iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS, "", "", iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);
                reader.Close();
                if (File.Exists(TargetFile.ToString()))
                    File.Delete(TargetFile.ToString());
                FinalFileName = ModifiedFileName.Remove(ModifiedFileName.Length - 5, 1);
                File.Copy(ModifiedFileName, FinalFileName);
                if (File.Exists(ModifiedFileName))
                    File.Delete(ModifiedFileName);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use this in mvc4? I am getting error in HtmlTextWriter,Response,GeneratePDF when I write same code in mvc?

Comment: what is this 'GeneratePDF'?